# Gigabit Ethernet only in LIVE session

Tags: networking, drivers, live-usb, ethernet

See bottom of this post for command line outputs...

Using an Ubuntu 18.04 variant (multiple tried with same results), a Laptop (Dell L502X) Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Realtek 8111/8168/8411) can provide a 1Gb/s connection in a live session, but once a given distro is installed to my HDD and booted, 1Gb/s ethernet is no longer the case, with an indicated connection speed of 100Mb/s.

No specific network configurations have been entered in either case; "/etc/network/interfaces" is untouched from defaults and has no entry for the ethernet adapter.  DHCP and Static IPv4 settings have both been attempted in the GUI network manager - all works, and with reliable connection, other than the speed issue just described.

Furthermore, the network infrastructure in use is several years mature and the standard 'hardware fault' question has been dismissed with substitute cables and machines, each of which provides 1Gb/s, notwithstanding the present problem case.

Outputs of "**sudo lshw -C network**":

**Under 18.04 as installed:**

```
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: enp6s0
       version: 06
       serial: 84:8f:69:d3:43:0d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.0.24 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1804000-f1804fff memory:f1800000-f1803fff
```

**In live (usb boot) session:**

```
   *-network
        description: Ethernet interface
        product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
        vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
        physical id: 0
        bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
        logical name: enp6s0
        version: 06
        serial: 84:8f:69:d3:43:0d
        size: 1Gbit/s
        capacity: 1Gbit/s
        width: 64 bits
        clock: 33MHz
        capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
        configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.1.130 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
        resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f1804000-f1804fff memory:f1800000-f1803fff
```

Comment: Too bad we don't know who gave the -1... there's a new idiot around who's downvoting and VTC unnecessarily. Don't worry about it. I'll do +1!

Comment: @heynnema I just noticed you did this.  You're a very helpful individual!  I recognize that my question is very long-winded and contains some superfluous detail, but it definitely doesn't match anything I could find with a few days' searching.  Not looking to score high (just solve the problem and maybe help someone else too), but it's nice to not get sunk during a maiden voyage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ethtool**

From `man ethtool`...

```
  ethtool -s devname [speed N] [duplex half|full] [port tp|aui|bnc|mii]
          [mdix auto|on|off] [autoneg on|off] [advertise N] [phyad N]
          [xcvr internal|external] [wol p|u|m|b|a|g|s|f|d...]
          [sopass xx:yy:zz:aa:bb:cc] [msglvl N | msglvl type on|off ...]
```

In the `terminal`...

`sudo ethtool -s enp6s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on`

`sudo lshw -C network`

**Update #1:**

Let's use a better driver than r8169...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install dkms r8168-dkms`

`reboot`

**Update #2:**

Here are three possible templates for making `ethtool` settings permanent. You'll have to do a little homework, and a little tinkering, to make sure it works as expected.

`man interfaces`

`sudo pico /etc/network/interfaces`

Add the following...

```
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet dhcp
    pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s enp6s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
```

or

```
# edit for the proper addresses
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet static
    pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s enp6s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
    address 192.168.1.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

or

```
auto enp6s0
iface enp6s0 inet manual
    pre-up /sbin/ethtool -s enp6s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on
```

Then reboot.

**Update #3:**

Couldn't get any stanza to work in /etc/network/interfaces, so we put `/sbin/ethtool -s enp6s0 speed 1000 duplex full autoneg on` in /etc/rc.local.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106537/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-gigabit-ethernet-only-in-live-session).

Comment: Update #3 works for startup and reboot, does not persist for suspend since /etc/rc.local is apparently not executed on resume (during which the interface is evidently reset).  Currently researching scripts for additional ethtool execution during resume...

Comment: For further reading regarding making this (ethtool setting) persistent, this page is also helpful: {https://serverfault.com/questions/463111/how-to-persist-ethtool-settings-through-reboot}

Comment: @JonathanWhittum I didn't see exactly what applied to you at that link... other than the fact we did things exactly right. I did have a minor epiphany though... tell me the result of `dpkg -l ifupdown | grep ii`. We should also reply in chat... just make sure to start comments there with "@heynnema", no quotes, or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: @JonathanWhittum Another epiphany... show me `grep -i manage /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`.